# How to get rid of `border-bottom` style in GNOME panel's button

Tags: gnome-shell

I want to make new gnome-shell theme which now the theming is lack of documentation yet.

Please look on the image below,

[image]

I want to get rid of the `border-bottom` (likely). And I tried in several ways and just change other element, not the one I mean.

Here, I try to manipulate element with .panel-button class,

```
.panel-button {
       border: 1px solid #ff0;
}

.panel-button:active,
.panel-button:checked,
.panel-button:focus,
.panel-button:hover,
.panel-button:overview {
       border: 1px solid #ff0;
}
```

But nope, it produce unexpected result.

Answer (score 3):

It's a strange way, but I myself found by looking inside gnome-shell-viva-theme source. 
We can use gradient with the same color,

```
.panel-button:active,
.panel-button:checked,
.panel-button:focus,
.panel-button:hover,
.panel-button:overview {
    background-gradient-direction: vertical;
    background-gradient-start: $bg-color;
    background-gradient-end: $bg-color;
}
```

It is not a perfect answer, still looking the better one.

Answer (score 1):

The property must to be changed is a `box-shadow` property.

```
#panel .panel-button:active,
#panel .panel-button:overview,
#panel .panel-button:focus,
#panel .panel-button:checked {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```